# How to access schema element annotation using Marklogic sc:annotations method

Tags: annotations, schema, marklogic

Given the following schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xdmp-annotations all?> <!-- Preserve documentation annotations -->
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://my-namespace/graphql" 
    xmlns:gql="http://my-namespace/graphql">

    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="height" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="appearsIn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="friends">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="person" type="gql:Person" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name='person' type='gql:Person'>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
            Person interface
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

how would I access the "person" element documentation?

The following code returns nothing:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import schema namespace gql ="http://my-namespace/graphql" at "/graphql/person.xsd";

let $element := element {xs:QName('gql:person')} {}
return 
<xml>
  {sc:element-decl($element) => sc:annotations()}
</xml>
```

According to the documentation, the processing instruction "`<?xdmp-annotations all?>`" should be enough to ensure documentation is returned in addition to the appinfo, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your namespaces don't match between the schema and the query, so what happens is you get a dummy schema for the namespace and that doesn't have a specific element declaration so it get treated as `anyType`.
2. You need to put the processing instruction inside the `xs:schema` element so that the schema parsing code sees it.

Fix those two things and your query works fine.

Comment: Sorry about the namespace confusion, I was trying to "anonymize" my example to hide my company's name... I have updated my question with "consistent" namespaces, as is my local version of the code. Regarding the processing instruction, unfortunately, even when I add it inside the xs:schema element the query still does not return the documentation. To be clear, I do get `<xml><xs:element name="person" type="gql:Person" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/></xml>` as a result to `<xml> {sc:element-decl($element)} </xml>`

Comment: oh, my bad...
I was importing the schema from another schema file and had omitted the `<?xdmp-annotations all?>` processing instruction there...It is working fine, many thanks for your help.